# Multiple JSON Providers at the same time with Resteasy and Jackson

Tags: jackson, resteasy, provider, objectmapper

Is is possible to have multiple JSON providers executing at the same time for the same content type(application/json)?

I want to include objectmapper configurations specific to my module in the application.

Is it possible to do this using the ContextResolver mechanism?

Thanks and Regards,
Jyothi